# Regex matching string containing at least x characters and x numbers

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a requirement to test if string matches following rules:

- Has at least 8 `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=]` characters and has at least 1 `[0-9]` number OR
- Has at least 8 `[0-9]` numbers and has at least 1 `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=]` character

So far I tried this:

```
"^(?=(?=.*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=].*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=].*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=].*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=].*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=].*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=].*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=].*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=])).{8,}\$")
```

It mostly works ok, but one scenario is failing:

```
"!abcdefgh1" --> matched (OK)
"{abcdefgh1" --> matched (NOT OK because character { shouldn't be allowed)
```

1. How to disallow any other characters except `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=]`?
2. Is it possible to write that regex in shorter way?

Thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance Only `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=]` and `[0-9]` should be allowed.

Comment: That's long but you need this `^(?:(?=(?:\d*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=]){8})[^\d\s]*\d|(?=(?:[^\s\d]*\d){8})\d*[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=])[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=\d]*$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/CvGQb9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `.`s are matching *any character*. To keep the convenience of using `.` to match a generic character but also require that the string doesn't contain any characters other than what's allowed, a simple tweak would be another lookahead at the beginning of the string to ensure that all characters before the end of the string are `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=]` or `[0-9]`, nothing else.

Also note that `[0-9]` simplifies to `\d`, which is a bit nicer to look at:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=\d]{9,}$) <rest of your regex>
```

You can also simplify your regex by *repeating* the big character set in a group, when possible, rather than writing it out manually 8 times. Also, as comment notes, when checking whether a string has enough digits, better to repeat `(?:\D*\d)` rather than using a dot, because you know that you want the antecedent to match non-digit characters.

Actually, because the initial lookahead above ensures that the string contains only digits and those certain non-digit characters, rather than repeating the long character set `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=]` again and again when matching a non-digit, you can just use `\D`, since the initial lookahead guarantees that non-digits *will* be within that character set.

For example:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=\d]+$)(?:(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:\d*\D){8})|(?=(?:\D*\d){8})(?=\d*\D))
```

Explanation:

`^(?=[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=\d]{9,}$)` - ensure string contains only desired characters (fail immediately if there are not at least 9 of them), then alternate between either:

`(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:\d*\D){8})` - string contains at least one digit, and 8 other characters, or

`(?=(?:\D*\d){8})(?=\d*\D)` - string contains at least 8 digits, and at least one of the other characters

https://regex101.com/r/18xtBw/2 (to test, input only one line at a time - otherwise, the `\D`s will match newline characters, which will cause problems)

Comment: `(?:.*\d){8}` to match 8 digits is a poor pattern. `(?:\D*\d){8}` is the right one. Use principle of contrast to get better performance.

Comment: Thanks, that does help! That also gave me the idea that there's no need to repeat the big character set anymore, except at the very beginning, because the lookahead ensures that later `\D`s will necessarily fit into that character set

Comment: `(?=[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&+=\d]+$)` - `+` can be replaced with `{9, }` to stop faster when a string length is less than 9

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance for help. I tried your regex and found one issue with it. It looks like following cases will be matched, but they shouldn't:
`@bcde@123456` (shouldn't be matched because it has 6 characters and 6 numbers)
`abcdefghabcdefgh`(shouldn't be matched because it has only characters without numbers)
I'm playing with your solution and maybe I'll be able to fix it. In case you see an error, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @DamirPalinić Those both look to fail as desired in regex101.

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you please check my example below? I see it as being matched while they shouldn't. Maybe I'm overlooking at something:
https://regex101.com/r/OFMMNb/1

Comment: @DamirPalinić Like I said in the answer, to test in the regex101, test only one line at a time, else the `\D`s, which match newlines too, will mess things up. See https://regex101.com/r/OFMMNb/2 (no match)

Comment: @DamirPalinić Also if it comes from user, you should ask them to not put newline characters while submitting data otherwise it will match.